# Can't build a go file with flag buildmode=plugin on mac

Tags: go

I'm doing a MIT lecture [lab](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-mr.html)

I ran in to errors with the line
`go build -race -buildmode=plugin ../mrapps/wc.go`, the error is :

````
In file included from _cgo_export.c:3:
/usr/local/include/stdlib.h:181:5: error: 'TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Werror,-Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_]```
````

Comment: Plugins work (a bit) on Linux. Don’t use plugins.

Comment: Are you using a current version of Go?

Comment: @JimB yes.. go1.18.2 darwin/amd64